# What's the best tactic vs Titans in Resistance 2?

Tags: resistance-2

It's kind of discouraging to get killed by Titans a lot in Resistance 2 and I'm wondering if I simply fail to see a weak spot or what I'm doing wrong.

So does anyone have an idea what the best tactics against Titans are?

[image]

Note: It's for the single player campaign, though any tips on what to do are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There really isn't a weak spot that I know of.

If you are talking about co-op, you really have to have teamwork to bring them down (especially on super difficulty mode).   You need at least 1 of each class usually.  The soldier's shields protect the team, the recon class keeps everyone with ammo, and the medic will keep everyone with health.

In the single player, I've used the bullseye, which allows you to mark a target. Mark the titan and then blast away, every shot will hit. On normal do that 3 or 4 times and he'll go down.

You might want to try the [**bullseye trap**](http://www.resistanceunion.com/weapons/bullseye.html) as well.

Comment: So there's no special weak spot I should aim for? And it's actually for the single player campaign

Comment: No, no weak spot.  Use the bullseye, which allows you to mark a target.  Mark the titan and then blast away, every shot will hit. On normal do that 3 or 4 times and he'll go down.  On godlike it takes a bit more but, still works. 


I've also added a link to the bullseye trap, which might work for you.

Answer (score 1):

The basics always apply.. (1) keep your distance - this will let you see those fireballs coming, you may be able to get out of the way. (2) keep moving - the titans seem to aim at you better when you stand still. (3) be aware of where to find cover - if you can break the titan's line of sight on you, this seems to confuse them a little bit. (4) be aware of 'splash damage' - a fireball only has to hit a wall near you to cause damage. This especially applies to objects *behind* you.

Regular sized chimera seem more susceptible to head shots, but I've never noticed titans to exhibit any such weakness, so I usually just aim for the upper body. Also, if you have grenades, don't bother saving them for later, smoke 'em if you got 'em.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is entirely true, titans do have weak spots in the head and on the back ( cooling apparatus ). LAARK and splicer can one shot titans at these areas. Augers work well for the same reason, the rounds burrow through the titan and hit these areas. But then again, you will have to try these out for yourself, I can't find any sources to back my claim other than my own playthroughs